# Can I access recently dialed numbers in IOS SDK?

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios

I'd like my iOS app to access numbers recently dialed by the user, or at least show a "recently dialed" default dialog and give the user an opportunity to select one of the phone numbers to import them into the app (something like address book import).

Is it possible using public apis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  There is no public API to access call records on stock iOS devices.